# Не подключается домен к репозиторию на GitHub

Tags: github, домен

Зарегистрировал домен, прописал в настройках DNS рекомендованные github IP-адреса с типом `A`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже проверил через утилиту `dig` всё ли верно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее создал репозиторий и в настройках, в секции `GitHub Pages` прописал имя домена в поле `Custom domain`. Сохранил. А GitHub мне такой:

> Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain,
>   indevelop.website, that's set up with an AAAA record. GitHub Pages
>   currently does not support IPv6.

И где он увидел DNS c типом `AAAA`, я не понимаю. Если чётко, и прямо прописал тип `A`. Это он тупит, или я?

Comment: Та же самая утилита `dig` показывает, что AAAA запись у этого домена очень даже есть. Откуда она там взялась — вам виднее

Comment: @andreymal А как Вы заметили там АААА? Я вижу только А.

Comment: Набрал `dig aaaa indevelop.website` да и всё

Comment: @andreymal а вот откуда она там взялась предположений нет? Это очень странно для меня.

Comment: Ну это уже вам виднее, где что как вы регистрировали и настраивали

Comment: @andreymal стандартные действия. Купил, и прописал DNS. Буквально два действия. Скорее всего тех. поддержка хостинга только поможет.